# forEach() repite datos de un array por cada llamada realizada a la función que lo contiene

Tags: javascript, html

He declarado la siguiente función que **agrega un evento click** a cada una de las **celdas** de una **tabla HTML**

```
// variables globales
let data = [];  
let c_key;

// función activada por el botón -recoger índice-
function cellSelector() {
    table.style.background = '#6165702c';
    // elimina todos los valores la siguiente vez que se llame a la funcion 
    data.splice(0);
    let td = table.querySelectorAll('td');

    c_key = true;
    td.forEach(c => {
        c.classList.add('td-hover');
        c.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // varible bandera que activara o desactivara el evento onclik 
            if (c_key) {
                // empujando índice cada vez que se realiza un click
                data.push(c.cellIndex);
                c.classList.add('td-selected');
            }
            
        });

        
    });

    td_action_flag = true;
    btn_done.disabled = false;
}
```

**el objetivo** es recolectar el **índice de la celda** a la que se le ha hecho **click** para realizar operaciones diversas a través de la manipulación del DOM. ej: guardar texto de la celda.

recoge correctamente los índices de las celdas y los gurda en un array (data), el problema reside cuando el botón que activa la función es **nuevamente presionado** este realiza la captura de los índices pero a la vez **duplica** los valores

**aclaración**:

se presiona el botón recoger índice por primera vez, luego se hace click sobre las celdas deseadas
**-** guarda en el array **data[index_1, index_2]** (muestra por consola). Operación Completada.

Se presiona el botón recoger índice nuevamente, guarda en el array **data[index_1, index_1, index_2, index_2]** duplicando los datos por cada llamada a la función

Espero me haya explicado bien.
Gracias.

Comment: Pon la declaracion de la variable data dentro de la función así cada vez que se ejecuta la función ese array estará vacío. si no va a duplicar resultados

Comment: tan sencillo, muchas gracias.
Aunque  he declarado también una variable externa para poder así mostrar el contenido del array data[] desde otro lugar

Answer (score 0):

He realizado los siguiente:

```
// variables globales
let c_key; 
let container; // variable global contenedora

// función activada por el botón -recoger índice-
function cellSelector() {

let data = [];
table.style.background = '#6165702c';
// elimina todos los valores la siguiente vez que se llame a la funcion 

let td = table.querySelectorAll('td');

c_key = true;
td.forEach(c => {
    c.classList.add('td-hover');
    c.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // varible bandera que activara o desactivara el evento onclik 
        if (c_key) {
            // empujando índice cada vez que se realiza un click
            data.push(c.cellIndex);
            c.classList.add('td-selected');
        }
    
    });
});

td_action_flag = true;
btn_done.disabled = false;

// almacenando array dentro de variable container
container = data;

data.splice(0);
}
```

para solucionar el problema del **duplicado**, he declarado el **array data** dentro de la función, y para tener a mano los valores de este lo he almacenado en una variable **contenedora** que esta declarada como variable global